# Integrate Stripe payment flow into django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I’m trying to integrate stripe custom payments flow into my Django ecom website as PayPal isn’t as good but the docs (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart?lang=python) for python are in the flask framework. Does anyone have boilerplate code for handling a simple transaction for this in Django (views, template etc.)

Answer (score 0):

**In theory**, the only thing that needs to change is the flask part of that code and change it into Django view(s).
The rest, html+js+css, should be able to be copied + pasted (especially cause the html is dynamically created by the Stripe JS)

##### views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# The GET checkout form
#
# urlpattern: 
#   path('checkout', views.checkout, name='checkout'),
def checkout(request):
    return render(request, 'checkout.html')

# The POST checkout form
#
# urlpattern: 
#   path('create-payment-intent', views.create_payment, name='create_payment'),
def create_payment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        import json
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.POST)

            def calculate_order_amount(items):
                # Replace this constant with a calculation of the order's amount
                # Calculate the order total on the server to prevent
                # people from directly manipulating the amount on the client
                return 1400

            # this api_key could possibly go into settings.py like:
            #   STRIPE_API_KEY = 'sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc'
            #
            # and fetched out with:
            #   from django.conf import settings
            #   stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_API_KEY

            import stripe
            stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc'

            # Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
            intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
                amount=calculate_order_amount(data['items']),
                currency='usd',
                automatic_payment_methods={
                    'enabled': True,
                },
            )
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps({'clientSecret': intent['client_secret']}),
                content_type='application/json'
            )
        except Exception as e:

            # Just return the 403 and NO error msg
            #   Not sure how to raise a 403 AND return the error msg
            from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

            # OR you could return just the error msg
            #   but the js would need to be changed to handle this
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps({'error': str(e)}),
                content_type='application/json'
            )

    # POST only View, Raise Error
    from django.http import Http404
    raise Http404
```

**Note:** You might also have to change the two urls in the .js to match your django URLS. What they have `"/create-payment-intent"` + `"http://localhost:4242/checkout.html"` (not sure why that 2nd one is full url, but remember to get the port correct)

---

This would just be the barebones that your URL you included shows, you still have to figure out how to get the `items` into `checkout.html`, dynamically pass them to the page + eventually to the POST and then redo `calculate_order_amount(items)`

Answer (score 0):

To understand working with Stripepayement I am sharing my GIT URL in which stripe payment is integrated you may refer

```
     https://github.com/KBherwani/BookManagement/
```